# How do I provide this countQuery to Query annotation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm moving my project from SDN 3 to SDN 4 and from Neo4j 2.3 to 3.0.1

I have a following Spring Data Neo4j repository  method:

```
 @Query(value = "START d=node:node_auto_index({autoIndexQuery}) MATCH (d:Decision) RETURN d", countQuery = "START d=node:node_auto_index({autoIndexQuery}) MATCH (d:Decision) RETURN count(*)")
 Page<Decision> searchDecisions(@Param("autoIndexQuery") String autoIndexQuery, Pageable page);
```

Right now in SDN 4 I can't find a way to provide this countQuery to Query annotation.

How it can be done in SDN 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paging for custom queries is not supported yet in SDN 4. The only option is to use skip and limit, passing in those parameters.

For example,

```
@Query(value = "START d=node:node_auto_index({autoIndexQuery}) MATCH (d:Decision) RETURN d ORDER BY d.something SKIP {skip} LIMIT {limit}")
 List<Decision> searchDecisions(@Param("autoIndexQuery") String autoIndexQuery, @Param("skip") int skip, @Param("limit") int limit);
```

Comment: When do you plan to add Paging support for custom queries to SDN ?

Comment: At the moment this hasn't been assigned to a specific release. You can track the issue here https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-653